# I with superscript ma

Tags: abbreviations

There is a footnote (45-35) in (Milman's 1845) Gibbon that looks like this:

See Brenkman, Dissert. I<sup>ma</sup> de Republicâ Amalphitanâ, pp.1-42, ad calcem Hist. Pandect. Florent.

I have not been able to decipher the I<sup>ma</sup>. I've found a couple of books that detail many of the Latin superscript abbreviations, but I haven't been able to find <sup>ma</sup> (or I<sup>ma</sup>) in those references. I've also found the source document (Historia pandectarum Florentinorum), and the De Republica Amalphitana at the end of it, but I see nothing in the title, etc. that would fit I<sup>ma</sup>, either.

Technically, I don't even *know* that it's Latin, but given that it's referring to a Latin dissertation in a Latin book, I'm assuming it is. I just haven't been able to track it down.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Prima (first). It’s a combination of a Roman numeral plus termination so you know what case/number it’s in.

The work referred to is here: http://dl.ub.uni-freiburg.de/diglit/brenkman1722/0489?sid=9f9dfd87b9bce3f41dae32f8d171b2a9

It’s titled “Gemina Dissertatio”, meaning “twin dissertations” or “two-fold dissertation.” The one about Amalfi is the first (prima) of the two parts.